# Generate single random number from Pygame Sprite Collision, currently multiple numbers generated

Tags: python, random, pygame

I am hacking the space invaders game from Python Crash Course. I'm using Python 3.5 and Pygame 1.9.2a0, groupcollide()

In the original, when bullets collide with spaceship both sprites are removed from screen.

In my version, I want the removal to me more random so that not all hits are successful.I have done this using the random module and making collisions successful if the random number is below a certain threshold (n). I have used the function in the code below, but it doesn't work as I want.

Using print(num) I have found that that random numbers are generated until    the num <=n is reached. I just want one number generated per collision.

I think this is happening because multiple collisions are detected as the bullet moves through the ships sprite rect. Testing this theory, if I remove bullet at collision then only 1 number is generated.

Q1. How can I keep bullet but only generate one number per sprite collision?

Q2. Do you have a better suggestion than using random numbers?

Any direction much appreciated, thanks

```
def check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, ship, aliens, bullets):

    """Respond to bullet-alien collisions."""

    #I swapped True, True to False, False below
    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, False, False)

    #I added this if statement

    if collissions:
        num = randrange(100)
        print (num) # lots of numbers generated just want 1
        if num <= 30:
            collissions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, True, True)

    #below in original code

    if len(aliens) == 0:
        # Destroy existing bullets, and create new fleet.
        bullets.empty()
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
        create_fleet(mi_settings, screen, decayingNucleus, ships)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give your `Bullet` class a `self.live` attribute and set it to `True` or `False` depending on the random number during the instantiation. Then iterate over the collided sprites and only call `enemy.kill()` if the bullet's `live` attribute is True.

```
import random
import pygame as pg


pg.init()

BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
ENEMY_IMG = pg.Surface((50, 30))
ENEMY_IMG.fill(pg.Color('darkorange1'))
BULLET_IMG = pg.Surface((9, 15))
BULLET_IMG.fill(pg.Color('aquamarine2'))


class Enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = ENEMY_IMG
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)


class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = BULLET_IMG
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(pos)
        self.vel = pg.math.Vector2(0, -450)
        # If `live` is True, the bullet is able to destroy an enemy.
        self.live = True if random.randrange(100) < 70 else False

    def update(self, dt):
        # Add the velocity to the position vector to move the sprite.
        self.pos += self.vel * dt
        self.rect.center = self.pos  # Update the rect pos.
        if self.rect.bottom <= 0:  # Outside of the screen.
            self.kill()


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))

        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.enemies = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.bullets = pg.sprite.Group()

        for i in range(15):
            pos = (random.randrange(30, 750), random.randrange(500))
            enemy = Enemy(pos)
            self.enemies.add(enemy)
            self.all_sprites.add(enemy)

        self.bullet_timer = .1
        self.done = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            # dt = time since last tick in milliseconds.
            dt = self.clock.tick(60) / 1000
            self.handle_events()
            self.run_logic(dt)
            self.draw()

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                bullet = Bullet(pg.mouse.get_pos())
                self.bullets.add(bullet)
                self.all_sprites.add(bullet)
                pg.display.set_caption('This bullet is live: {}'.format(bullet.live))

    def run_logic(self, dt):
        mouse_pressed = pg.mouse.get_pressed()
        self.all_sprites.update(dt)

        # hits is a dict. The enemies are the keys and bullets the values.
        hits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(self.enemies, self.bullets, False, True)
        for enemy, bullet_list in hits.items():
            for bullet in bullet_list:
                # Only kill the enemy sprite if the bullet is live.
                if bullet.live:
                    enemy.kill()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Game().run()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: thanks for this, I will try to incorporate over the next week and let you know how it goes, too busy to do it now unfortunately as its my weekend project, wish it was the other way around haha